# x11docker, display not working

Tags: x11, docker

i want to run GUI apps in docker using x11docker but some display issues are making it impossible, I'm new to docker so I've run out of things to try.

[GitHub x11docker repo](https://github.com/mviereck/x11docker?tab=readme-ov-file#examples)

Things break when i try to launch any application, I'll give some examples, the corresponding images for each app are downloaded.

**ERROR 1:**

```
x11docker --xephyr x11docker/fvwm xterm #command to run xterm in container
```

Output:

```
x11docker [17:06:47,989]: Starting Xpra server
Warning: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR is not defined
and '/run/user/1000' does not exist
using '/tmp'
you must install `xpra-x11` to use `seamless #this keeps appearing even tho i have xpra installed
last lines of xpra client log:
x11docker [17:06:48,009]: Starting Xpra client
(xpra:98858): Gtk-WARNING **: **:**:**.***: cannot open display:
```

**ERROR 2**:

```
x11docker --xorg x11docker/fvwm xterm
```

Output:

```
x11docker ERROR: waitforlogentry(): start_container(): Found error message in logfile. Last lines of logfile xinit.log:
Fatal server error: no screens found 
Please also check the log file at "/var/log/Xorg.129.log" for additional information.# this folder doesn't even exist
```

If i run it without using --xorg or --xephyr i get the same ***ERROR 1***, i also tried mounting a dockerfile that opens google and got this output:

```
Missing X server or $DISPLAY
```

My *DISPLAY* and *XAUTHORITY* variables are empty when i do `echo $DISPLAY` or `echo $XAUTHORITY` so im using `export DISPLAY=$(cat /etc/resolv.conf | grep nameserver | awk '{print $2}'):0` to give a value to DISPLAY, the value keeps reseting to *none* after a while.

All the errors lead to a display issue but can't seem to find what to do. Just let me know if i need to provide something more to give the post better context and understanding, thanks.

Comment: Does the Quick Start Guide in the link you provided work?

Comment: installation yes, easy to use examples no

Answer (score 0):

So i was using two pc's for this, one was a minipc with only ubuntu server, that was the problem. you need to have deskpot version in order to work.